# Batch file: Combine string of two columns in another column

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, substring

I am currently trying to automate the preprocessing process of my csv data.
My csv table looks like this:

```
id;      town;   nrlanes;   direction;   name;            x;       y;        edgeid;     
129001;  Wales;  1;         Scottland;   Scottland B10;   54529;   338288;   E332;
111002;  Wales;  2;         London;      London B12;      54529;   338288;   E304;
334003;  Wales;  3;         Ireland;     Ireland B3;      54529;   338288;   E303;
```

What I am trying to do is to overwrite the column "name" with a combination of the columns id(the last 3 digits should be cut!) and direction (+ the string "Ri." should be in put in before the direction). The result table should look like this:

```
id;      town;   nrlanes;   direction;   name;                x;       y;        edgeid;     
129001;  Wales;  1;         Scottland;   129 Ri. Scottland;   54529;   338288;   E332;
111002;  Wales;  2;         London;      111 Ri. London;      54529;   338288;   E304;
334003;  Wales;  3;         Ireland;     334 Ri. Ireland;     54529;   338288;   E303;
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
@echo off
REM for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=;" %%a in (%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%temp.csv) do echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%~a Ri. %%~d;%%e;%%f;%%g >> "%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%"

(
for /F "tokens=1-8* delims=;" %%a in (%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%temp.csv) do (
  set id=%%a
  set id_cut=%id:~-3%
  set merged_columns=%id_cut% Ri. %%~d
  echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;%merged_columns%;%%f;%%g
 )
)>> "%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%"
```

I have read in another thread that %var_name:~-3% cuts the last three digits of a string and that is exactly what I need.
Here is the result of my bat file version:

```
id;      town;   nrlanes;   direction;   ;   x;       y;        edgeid;     
129001;  Wales;  1;         Scottland;   ;   54529;   338288;   E332;
111002;  Wales;  2;         London;      ;   54529;   338288;   E304;
334003;  Wales;  3;         Ireland;     ;   54529;   338288;   E303;
```

As you can see, the column "name" is empty and also the column name "name" is empty. What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using windows and the bat file is executed via cmd line

Comment: after `@echo off` do `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` then change `set id_cut=%id:~-3%` to `set id_cut=!id:~-3!` and also change `echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;%merged_columns%;%%f;%%g` to `echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;!merged_columns!;%%f;%%g`

Comment: no, don't change it in your question, change it in your script.

Comment: @Gerhard Hey, I updated my question with your suggestion, but the solution is not quite what wanted. The id is missing and the column name should not change to "Ri. direction" (it should stay "name").

Comment: ok, let me have a look at this quick.

Comment: Does your csv file really have content which looks like this: `id;      town;   nrlanes;   direction;   name;            x;       y;        edgeid;     `? My guess is that it should look more like this, `id;town;nrlanes;direction;name;x;y;edgeid;`. In your output file, you appear to have omitted part of the fifth field content, i.e. `B10`, `B12`, `B3`, is that intended? because you have not mentioned it in your body text.

Comment: @user7335295, Have you got any intention of correcting your question based upon my previous comment? It is important because you've currently accepted an answer which does not produce the layout shown in your result table, and more importantly the content of the `name` field does not match the value you've provided either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you require `delayedexpansion`

Note where I had to replace `%` with `!` to expand the variables, which are being `set` in the parenthesized loop. I also assume you do not have all the whitespace?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6* delims=;" %%a in (%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%temp.csv) do (
   set "id=%%a"
   echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;!id:~0,-3! Ri. %%~d;%%f;%%g
 )
)>"%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%"
```

Lastly, consider what your result will do to the header, if this is not required, you need to `skip=1` and then modify the header to suit your needs. Here is an example to retain the original header:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%temp.csv) do (
   (echo %%a)>"%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%" & goto :file
)
:file
(for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6* delims=;" %%a in (%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%temp.csv) do (
   set "id=%%a"
   echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;!id:~0,-3! Ri. %%~d;%%f;%%g
 )
)>>"%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%"
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the header and then reassembling it unchanged, why not simply leaving it as a single token? `for /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%a in …`. Alternatively, you could just do this: `< "%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%temp.csv" set /P head=`, then `> "%PREPROCESSING_OUTPUT_PATH%%OUTPUT_FILENAME%" echo(%head%`…

Comment: @aschipfl, thanks, yes. I kind off copied the original for loop when I created the answer, edited. thanks again.

Comment: Hey Gerhard, somehow this solution does not print the headers of the column into the output file. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: The second example does exactly that. it will extract the header as is, then the loop will do the manipulation. Can you show what you have changed in the code?